# How to Auto Add User ID's to Code

Tags: insert

```
<script type="text/javascript src="http://www.mysite.com/services/share_widget/111111/i/mm-glossy_64"></script>
```

User Id "111111" How is this inserted for each User ID?

Thanks,

Kelly

Comment: This is not a question. 'Inserted' to what? You need to add more information; there's no way of telling from this what you're actually asking or trying to do.

Comment: You should post a little more info on what you're trying to accomplish and what your environment is.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what you've got on the back-end here's how you'd do it in a ASP.Net MVC View:

```
....
....
<script type="txt/javascript" src="/services/share_widget/<%= Model.UserId %>/i/mm-glossy_64"></script>
....
....
```